# gnu toolchain; bare meta aarch64l; osx host platform;

Tags: arm, gnu, arm64, toolchain, bare-metal

I'm looking for a GNU toolchain:

- target platform is aarch64 bare metal (cortex-a53/armv8-a)
- host Mac OSX

Or by other words I need a bunch of `aarch64-none-elf-*` files

Any advise where could I get these tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the -none- version of the toolchain anymore on aarch64. You can simply use `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` for instance, with the right parameters (no standard libs or headers):

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -march=armv8-a -nostdinc -fno-builtin -c -o main.o main.c
```

Comment: Right, is there a stash with `aarch64-linux-gnu-*` binaries then?